# add and remove dynamic input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have a dynamic number of input field and also able to remove it. I can do it if this is only client side but I am getting the data from server and the issue is that I am not getting the id from the server, and that I need to be able to change the number of fields on the fly in the UI.

since I am also getting some fields from the server the manually added id was not longer in sync with the # of items.

How do i achieve this?

Here is my code

```
let _id = 0;

function guid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4();
}

class Rules extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      rules: {
        rule_regulations: {}
      },
      numberOfInput: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadRules();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.rules.size && nextProps.rules !== this.props.rules) {
      nextProps.rules
        .entrySeq()
        .map(([key, value]) => {
          this.setState(state => ({
            rules: {
              ...state.rules,
              rule_regulations: {
                ...state.rules.rule_regulations,
                [key]: value
              }
            },
            numberOfInput: [...state.numberOfInput, guid()]
          }));
        })
        .toArray();
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      rules: {
        ...this.state.rules,
        rule_regulations: {
          ...this.state.rules.rule_regulations,
          [name]: value
        }
      }
    });
  };

  handleAddRules = e => {
    this.setState({
      numberOfInput: [...this.state.numberOfInput, guid()]
    });
  };

  handleRemoveRules = (e, num) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      numberOfInput: this.state.numberOfInput.filter(input => input !== num)
    });
  };

  handleSave = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const obj = {
      rule_regulations: Object.values(this.state.rules.rule_regulations)
    };
    this.props.postRules(obj);
  };

  render() {
    const { numberOfInput } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="basic-property">
        <span className="circleInputUi" onClick={this.handleAddRules}>
          +
        </span>
        <RulesInputContainer
          numberOfInput={numberOfInput}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          handleRemoveRules={this.handleRemoveRules}
          handleSave={this.handleSave}
          value={this.state.rules.rule_regulations}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const RulesInputContainer = props => {
  return (
    <div className="rules-input">
      {props.value &&
        Object.keys(props.value).map(key =>
          <RulesInput
            key={key}
            num={key}
            value={props.value}
            handleChange={props.handleChange}
            handleRemoveRules={props.handleRemoveRules}
          />
        )}
      <button className="button" onClick={props.handleSave}>
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RulesInputContainer;


const RulesInput = props => {
  return (
    <form className="form">
      <InputField
        label={`Rule ${props.num + 1}`}
        type="text"
        name={`${props.num}`}
        value={props.value[props.num] || ""}
        onChange={props.handleChange}
      />
      <Button onClick={e => props.handleRemoveRules(e, props.num)}>
        Remove
      </Button>
    </form>
  )
  }
```

I want the synchronization with server data and client

Answer (score -1):

You can store returned data from your server into your component `state`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.loadRules();
}

loadRules() {
  let rules = this.props.loadRules();
  this.setState({rules});
}
```

You can keep the synchronization by setting your `state` with data you received from your server.

In addition, it's not related to your question. Since `RulesInputContainer` and `RulesInput` are presentational components I think you can combine those into 1 component.

Comment: this.props.loadRules() is not a data. Its a function for calling an api to load the data

Comment: And where do you store your fetched/loaded data ?

Comment: In componentWillReceiveProps()

Comment: If so, I am assuming you are fetching data from the parent component. Then do something and pass that "data" to `Rules`. If so I don't think you have any problem because you can manipulate your data. I'm sorry but what is your problem anyway?